# Django - Get a list of repeated queryset results from a list of values

Tags: python, django

I have the following model named Profile, which has a field named address

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Anyway, I have a list like this one, which contains the primary keys of certain users.

```
pks=[1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

I need to make a Queryset which filters the users who are in that list, returning the value of its address no matter how many times one user appear in the pks list. Hence, I have done the queryset as follows:

```
Profile.objects.filter(pk__in=pks).values_list('address', flat=True))
```

The problem is that I'm getting something like this:

```
['address 1', 'address 2', 'address 3']
```

And I need something like this:

```
['address 1', 'address 1', 'address 2', 'address 1', 'address 3']
```

P.S: I'm trying to avoid using a for loop, because the pks list can grow very large, and it wouldn't be efficient for the DB... So, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it seems the result you need is not necessarily a queryset, but a list of objects retrieved from the queryset.

From my knowledge, there is no way to achieve the desired result directly through Django's ORM.

However, to avoid unnecessary hits on the database, I would suggest to create the desired list *after* your query, for example like so:

```
pks=[1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
queryset = Profile.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)
result_list = [queryset.get(pk=item).address for item in pks]
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise! If I can't find any other way, I'll do it like you say

Comment: You are welcome. Accepting the answer would be great then :-)